# Which AES mode to use to encrypt email addresses in a database?

Tags: python, aes, pycrypto

I'm encrypting email addresses stored in my database using AES before storing them. I want to be able to tell if the email has already been added to the database. This means when I call `encrypt(email)` the result must always be the same for the same input email, because otherwise I'd have to decrypt every email to see if it matches.

I have am currently doing this using CFB mode with a contant IV, which gives the desired result. For any aes encryption which is not for this email field I'm using a different key and a random IV, which is [the recommended way of doing AES CFB encryption](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.Cipher.blockalgo-module.html#MODE_CFB).

My questions are:

- Which AES mode suits this use case best?
- How damaging is it to reuse the same IV?
- Is encrypting emails to store in the database considered bad practice and why? (assuming my database is secured properly in the first place)